# Weeping Willow in trouble

Tags: insects

Something looks like it’s making holes in the limbs and trunk. No insects present, but Weeping Willow trees are dying. Any idea what it is and how to treat to save the trees?

Comment: What part of the world are you in (pests differ according to  location) and can you add a  photo or two?

Comment: Are they woodpecker-sizes holes? If they are, they're probably not what's killing the tree.

Comment: Woodpeckers don't kill trees - the borers that the woodpeckers eat do.